# visual c# 2008 database application examples

Tags: c#, database, offline

i just have a few weeks programming with vc# (2008) and i'm trying to build an application  (winforms) and i have the following problem... i need my application to work with and without connection to the mssql database, this sounds like piece of cake for our friend DataSet right? i can persist the data as XML or binary until i can reach  the database and the DataSet will magically sync; all without bothering the user.
The problem is... the few books i have read just mention that logic like a fairy tale but dont give any practical example of how to do it, can you point me to one example/demo/whatever i can read or download of an application with (equal or) similar logic?

Comment: You really should change your question title. Your question is more about persisting DataSets to disk than searching for application examples.

Answer (score 1):

To serialize should be just this simple:

```
Binary.BinaryFormatter formatter = new Binary.BinaryFormatter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // populate data set
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\dataset.bin", FileMode.CreateNew)) 
    {
        ds.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
        formatter.Serialize(fs, ds);
    }
```

to deserialize:

```
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\dataset.bin", FileMode.Open)) 
    {
        formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        DataSet ds = (DataSet)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

    }
```

(Roughly... not near compiler for proper testing)

Comment: And if you want to serialize via XML: http://www.diranieh.com/NETSerialization/XMLSerialization.htm#Examples%20of%20XML%20Serialization

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DataSet, you can just use [DataSet.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) and [DataSet.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx). Or am I missing something?